# Как наиболее быстро сохранить/прочитать std::unordered_map в файл

Tags: c++, файлы, c++11, словари, map

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке:
**Как наиболее быстро сохранить/прочитать std::unordered_map в файл**
Значение и ключ --> строки.

P.S. в мапе не больше 1000 записей

Comment: Поскольку конкретная реализация зависит от компилятора, то как-то напрямую вряд ли возможно. Просто пишите все пары поочередно, а потом так же поочередно читайте и вносите в таблицу... 1000 записей - не то количество (если строки не мегабайтные), чтоб стоило беспокоиться о скорости...

Comment: @Harry строки по 256 символов

Comment: Ну, 512 килобайт в сумме - очень небольшое количество, так что, по-моему, простые поочередные запись/считывание вполне адекватны.

Comment: @Harry можете привести код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Защиту от дурака" - все проверки, что файл открылся, существует, запись прошла и так далее - не писал, это уж сами допишите. Главное - файл открывать в бинарном режиме.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

ostream& outStr(ostream& out, const string& s)
{
    size_t l = s.size();
    out.write((char*)&l,sizeof(l));
    out.write(s.c_str(),l);
    return out;
}

istream& inStr(istream& in, string& s)
{
    size_t l;
    in.read((char*)&l,sizeof(l));
    s = string(l,' ');
    in.read(s.data(),l);
    return in;
}


void map2file(const unordered_map<string,string>& m, ostream& out_file)
{
    size_t l = m.size();
    out_file.write((char*)&l,sizeof(l));
    for(auto& p: m)
    {
        outStr(out_file,p.first);
        outStr(out_file,p.second);
    }
}

void file2map(istream& in_file, unordered_map<string,string>& m)
{
    size_t l;
    in_file.read((char*)&l,sizeof(l));
    for(int i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    {
        string key;
        inStr(in_file,key);
        inStr(in_file,m[key]);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    unordered_map<string,string> m = {
        {"aaa", "111" },
        {"bbb", "222" },
        {"ccc", "333" },
        {"ddd", "444" },
        {"eee", "555" }
    }, p;

    {
        ofstream out("data",ios::binary);
        map2file(m,out);
    }
    {
        ifstream in("data",ios::binary);
        file2map(in,p);

        for(auto& s: p) cout << s.first << "  " << s.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: не углядели по моему один момент, в циклах `for` когда итерируетесь по `map` лучше по ссылке брать пару

Comment: @Ildar Да, вы правы. Спасибо!

Comment: @Harry Огроменное спасибище! И С Новым Годом!

Comment: Как-то странно в `inStr(istream& out` смотрится `out` для потока `istream` :)

Comment: @Mikhailo OK, исправил. Просто copy-paste никто не отменял :)